# Build alternate cell range vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, alternate

my intent of building a dynamic alternate cells range as failed, obviously for lack of knowledge.

```
For j = 1 To numFrame
    Set MaxStRange_OD_OUT = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2 * (j + 1)))
    MaxVal = Application.Max(MaxStRange_OD_OUT)
    Debug.Print MaxVal
Next j
```

what I would like to achive is

```
MaxStRange_OD_OUT = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 4),Cells(1, 6),Cells(1, 8))
```

of course the number of cells can vary let say from 1 to 10 (numFrame)

thanks

Comment: Do you need to use macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Application.Union` to build up a range.

```
Sub UnionRangeExample()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 20 Step 2

    If rng Is Nothing Then

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

    Else

    Set rng = Application.Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1))
    End If

    Next i

MsgBox rng.Address

End Sub
```

---

In your situation you can use it like this:

```
Sub UnionRangeExample_v2()

Dim rng As Range
Dim j As Long
Dim numFrame As Long


numFrame = 10


    For j = 1 To numFrame
        If rng Is Nothing Then

        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2 * (j + 1))

        Else

        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2 * (j + 1)))
        End If
    Next j

MsgBox "max for: " & rng.Address & " is " & Application.Max(rng)

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line? I did just write it and test it on my PC with no issues.

Comment: @fabio.geraci I just added another example that you should be able to use in your situation (again I tested this without issue).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code here

```
Function MyMaxValue() as Double
    Dim maxValue As Double, numFrame As Double, i As Integer, currentValue As Double

    numFrame = 7

    For i = 1 To numFrame
        currentValue = Cells(1, 2 * (j + 1)).value
        If currentValue > maxValue Then
            maxValue = currentValue
            Debug.Print "new value = " & maxValue
        End If
    Next i

    MyMaxValue = maxValue    
End Function
```

Comment: is there a way to transform all the values in the range before calculating the max value

Comment: Yes you can use Union() and then Max(). But the question is why do you want a Range with this values? My code reach the same goal with the same speed (of better) and i think it is more clear then Range variable and so on.

Comment: Makah, i am new to vba so i work with what i know, but your code will suit perfectly, specially cos i need the abs val to over the values, thanks

Comment: tried your suggestion but it does not pass the correct value to the next operation

Comment: It does not pass value at all. It's a Sub not a Function. I edit the code return the maxValue for you.